# how to check if it was the last element

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I check if it was the last div? If it was I need to remove all classes "ready"

html:

```
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="orange"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="orange"></div>
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(showBlock, 1000);
    function showBlock() {
        var x = $("div:first").addClass("ready");
        var c = $("div");
        $(".ready").css("display", "block");
        if (c.hasClass("ready")) {
            $(".ready:last").next().addClass("ready");
        }
    }
})
```

;

Comment: Use `.is(':last')` - although what are you expecting to happen when the last element is reached? There may be ways to improve your logic.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: **I need to remove all classes "ready"** what do you want exactly by this?

Comment: when the last element has class "ready" - it shows, after  this all elements disappear and then everything will start again

Comment: It seems very confusing differentiating that **what is actually happening** and **what do you want to be happened**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code what I understand is you want display one div after each second. For that I'll suggest following approach.
First add `hidden` class to all `div`s and then remove it from first `hidden div` at each second.

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').addClass('hidden');
  var i = setInterval(showBlock, 1000);
  function showBlock() {
    var x = $("div.hidden:first").removeClass("hidden");
    if($("div.hidden").length == 0) {
      clearInterval(i);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="green">Green</div>
<div class="orange">Orange</div>
<div class="red">Red</div>
<div class="green">Green</div>
<div class="orange">Orange</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your problem, following solution must work in your case:

```js
$(function() {
  setInterval(showBlock, 1000);
  function showBlock() {
    var ready_divs = $("div.ready").length;
    var total_divs = $("div").length;
    if(ready_divs!=total_divs){
      if(ready_divs==0){
        $("div:first").addClass('ready');
      }else{
        $("div.ready:last").next('div').addClass('ready');
      }
    }else{
      $("div").removeClass('ready')
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
div.ready{
    border:3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="orange"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="orange"></div>
```